# Android & phonegap pass parameters to html page

Tags: android, json, cordova

How can I pass a json variable to my html page in Android, using PhoneGap?

My code:

```
public class Activity extends DroidGap {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String json = readFile();

    // I would pass json to menu.html
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/menu.html");
}
};
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the localStorage to pass your json.

```
window.localstorage.setItem("Json", json);
```

and when you want to get this json

```
string json = window.localstorage.getItem("Json");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only be doing this if you are writing a Cordova (PhoneGap) plugin. If this is the case, you should be extending CordovaPlugin, not DroidGap. Then you will be able to return data to the JavaScript via a PluginResult object or the convenience method `callbackContext.success(json)` Have a look at the [Plugin Development Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.6.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide), specifically the page on developing for Android.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    super.init();

    myclass = new MyClass(this, appView);
    appView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "MyTeam");       

    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/menu.html");
}
```

and

```
 public class MyClass {

    private WebView mAppView;
    private DroidGap mGap;

    public MyClass(DroidGap gap, WebView view){


        mAppView = view;
        mGap = gap;
    }
 }
```